# How to match list of areas to a "address"(string) and get the area which is present in both list and string Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, lis

Hello every one i have string containing **Address** and list of **Areas** from Db, i want to get the area from **address** string which is present in both list of **areas** and **address** string.how can i do this without looping because through looping it will take to much time. Any solution please through regular expression or any other approach.

```
  var data = _context.OrderDetails.Where(c => c.ConsignmentId == cId)
            .Select(c => new {address = c.DeliveryAddress, cityId = c.CityId}).ToList();
        string EncryptedConsId = _customEncryptionDecryption.Encode(cId);

        Regex re = new Regex(@"^(.*?(\bkarachi\b)[^$]*)$");
        MatchCollection cityA = re.Matches(data[0].address.ToLower());
        if (cityA.Count != 0)
        {
            var cityNameA = cityA[0].Groups[2];
            if (cityNameA.Value == "karachi")
            {
                var areasForCityA = _context.Areas.Where(a => a.CityId == 1).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi can you show an example, pseudo code, or similar? Also; why do you think a regex is faster than a loop? Can you express your worst case in `O`?

Comment: i have almost 290 or 294 areas in a single list , that's why i think that it will take time but its a one time activity , if i'm wrong please guide me to the right path.

Comment: Please show us an **example** of addresses and areas what you have as input and what is the expected output

Comment: i have updated my question please check it  i have attached a code sample after getting areas i want to preform match between list of areas and address string

Comment: BTW If you have a list and you have to compare each item of the list then there is no solution without looping. Even when you use regex - how do you think does regex its job?

Comment: I have no idea about regex execution sir ,i'm searching for optimal solution ,

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < areasForCityB.Count; i++)
         {
             var result = data[0].address.Trim().Contains(areasForCityB[i].Title.Trim());
                if (result)
                 {
                       var area = areasForCityB[i].Title;
                       var areaId = areasForCityB[i].Id;
                  }
         }`

Comment: this solution  is not working because  Area ="Sukh Chain Society"  and Address="12/A/2 north avenue sukh chain Socity Lahore" both contain spaces how  can i perform match between these 2

Comment: How about properly normalizing your data and then do it with a join?

Answer (score 0):

i have solve my problm by doing this,Thanks to all of You Thank you so much

```
 var areas = _context.Areas.Where(a => a.CityId == data[0].cityId).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < areas.Count; i++)
        {
            var result = data[0].address.ToLower().Contains(areas[i].Title.ToLower());
            if (result)
            {
                AreaId = areas[i].Id;
                CityId = data[0].cityId;
                var order = _context.OrderDetails.Where(o => o.ConsignmentId == cId).SingleOrDefault();
                order.AreaId = AreaId;
                _context.SaveChanges();
                break;
            }
        }
```